# parsing using multiple delimiters in python

Tags: python, parsing, delimiter

I have a data file in which data is stored with comma and tab and newline delimiter like this

```
[32135,    311351,    88686
123152,    3153131,    131513
....]
```

i want to extract a nx3 array out of it 
how could i do that ?

have tried using split in splitlines but it just parsed the file partially

```
import numpy as np
filename="Elem_Output.inp"
f = open(filename,"r")
pmax=f.read()
p1=pmax.split()
```

i expect to extract an array with every line a row and the numbers in each column in the arrays' column

Comment: does your text file have the `[` characters?

Comment: @MarkMeyer no it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pmax=f.read(), you may want to write:

```
#Replace tab and newline as comma separater
pmax = pmax.replace("\n",",").replace("\t", ",")

#Replace repeated delimiter by a single instance
pmax = pmax.replace(",,,",",").replace(",,",",")
```

Needless to say, this can be coded much better using regex (import re).

Secondly, if your file starts and ends with square brackets, you may want to additionally add:

```
pmax = pmax.replace("[","").replace("]","")
```

Now, if you want this output as an array instead of list, try this:

```
from array import array
array_pmax = array("B", pmax)
```

The first argument in the array() function indicates the typecode. To know more, just use help(array)

Hope that helps!!

Comment: tnx it worked but it gives me a list and i need an array

Comment: Welcome. I have now updated the answer to handle your array requirement.
This should help :)